# Chrome Extension no data is surviving the popup refresh

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, session-storage

Pre: I'm in chrome and logged in

1. I launch (click on) my popup window. It saves some data in all storages (windowlocal, windowsession, google local and google sync)
2. I right click on it, and choose inspect.
3. The dev tools window comes up for the popup
4. I look in Storage Explorer in Dev Tools, I see all my data is there, in all storages.[image]
5. I put a breakpoint at the start of my popup.js code. This breakpoint is before it loads any data or does anything. It's at the beginning of the constructor.
6. I hit F5 on the Dev Tools window. It flickers and comes back

Expected Result: I see all the data I've saved

Actual Result: No data whatsoever is there, in any of the storages. It's all gone.

What am I doing wrong? Is popup not supposed to be able to save data?

Comment: How do you initialize your storage?

Comment: Even if I save using chrome.storage.local in the popup it disappears when I close the popup.

Comment: Storage Explorer is itself an extension, it can't run when you paused the JS environment.

Comment: The only other explanation is that your code is deleting the data.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with absolute minimum code? Like nothing there but one line that saves current time in storage. And also, have you checked with different browser/profile with no other extensions?

Comment: @vanowm, nope, it won't reproduce then. Once I removed my code that saves to storage, the problem went away. The data remained. Luckily all my save code is centralized in just three lines, not spread out over the whole app.

Comment: @vanowm, if you meant initialize my popup, yes there's storage interactivity there, and when I commented that out, the problem went away. Maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: In that case since it's all centralized, you can add some kind of logging so you could see when/what does what with the storage.

Comment: @vanowm, unfortunately, console.stack() doesn't give the whole stack, just the property setter containing the storage saving line of code. But what I *can* do is put breakpoints in the storage saving setter and hit F5 to make it re-init, and see the stack trace then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues

1. If you put a breakpoint in the constructor of an extension on dev tools, it's likely that storage explorer won't show anything, because it hasn't loaded yet
2. In my constructor, I was loading the settings correctly from storage, but then immediately overwriting them with the default values because I was calling load() first, and it had become asynchronous, and further down in my code in my settings property setters were re-saving the default values, so by the time load() resolved itself to execute, it was just reading the (just) saved default values.

### Solution

I brought the load code out of the constructor into an `async` function, and called that function right at the end of my constructor. In that function, I used `await` to make sure the settings were loaded from storage, then continued to set the settings properties.